# Python 3: An easy way to print a long list of numbers without running off the page

Tags: python-3.x, list, numpy, printing

I want to print a long list of numbers (with or without the enclosing square brackets) so that it doesn't run off the page. I would like to avoid splitting the list into chunks in a loop or other such devices if possible. I am happy to specify how many numbers in a row (15 here) but not the number of lines. If I convert my list to a numpy array then the resultant output is ideally what I want, but I'm ok with 15 columns. Is there a neat way to do this in python3? This is what I tried.

Code is:

```
import numpy as np
long_list = [n for n in range(113)]
print('Print as list')
print(long_list)
print('Print in rows of 15 - but only get first 15 elements')
print(('\t{}'*15).format(*long_list))
print('Convert to numpy array and print that')
np_long_list = np.array(long_list)
print(np_long_list)
```

Output is:

```
Print as list
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112]
Print in rows of 15 - but only get first 15 elements
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14
Convert to numpy array and print that
[  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17
  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35
  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53
  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71
  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89
  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107
 108 109 110 111 112]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pprint`  with `compact=True`

**Ex:**

```
from pprint import pprint

long_list = [n for n in range(113)]
pprint(long_list, compact=True)
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21,
 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41,
 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61,
 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81,
 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100,
 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112]
```

---

You can adjust the width using the `width` param

**Ex:**

```
pprint(long_list, width=50, compact=True)
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14,
 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26,
 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38,
 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50,
 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62,
 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74,
 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86,
 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98,
 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108,
 109, 110, 111, 112]
```

**[MoreInfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html)**